# Volume Slider Keeps Muting Automatically

Tags: javascript, audio, slider, volume

I am creating a responsive audio player from scratch using HTML 5, jQuery and Amplitude.js for Live streaming.

On the right side of the player is a "Speaker Icon" that when clicked, mutes the volume, but when simply hovered displays a vertical volume slider.

When the volume slider handle is in the MouseDown state, the audio levels decrease or increase accordingly. However after selection when the handle enters a MouseUp state, the slider handle jumps to the bottom, effectively muting the volume.

I have tried to use JavaScript to deactivate the  Mute/Unmute toggle class created for the Speaker Icon button as the Volume Slider is a Range Slider within a Child-div of the Mute/Unmute div, however I am still not able to stop the slider from muting upon MouseUp.

Please help.

The code written in an attempt to disable the ToggleClass is as follows:

```
$(function volmute() {
$("#amplitude-mute").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("unmute mute").siblings().removeClass("unmute mute");
 });
});
```

[full jsFiddle of player](http://jsfiddle.net/LibertyTalkFM/3fxj08ow/39/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fxj08ow/44/) Link

Because you have not added any event on volume slider. And added click event on the volume container `amplitude-mute`. So on every click of slider range volume is getting mute and unmute.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance I very much appreciate your time. Please forgive me as my skill level with javascript is hacky to say the least.

When I looked at the jsFiddle, the volume now stays, but the slider still disappears and the audio and speaker icon turns to mute. When clicking on the mute icon the volume does go back to where I had previously set the range on the slider?